# i want to host a php site on apache2 on port 82. how will be the virtual host config file? I am new

Tags: php, apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ServerAdmin abc@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/crm_new
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ServerName air.in
  ServerAlias www.air.in
</VirtualHost>
```

this is my config file. but it not loading index.php

Comment: you can refer this article for understanding the procedure    https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- Removing any directives you have listed twice (eg. DocumentRoot, ErrorLog, CustomLog)
- Remember that every time you change this file, you need to restart Apache.
- When you restart Apache, pay attention to any warnings/errors that display, as these will tell you if you if there are any problems.
- Have a look at the log file you specified in ErrorLog ("tail /path/to/log/file") to see if any problems are listed.
- If any of the log files you listed don't exist, you may need to create them first and make sure they are writeable by the Apache user.
- Before trying to get php working, try getting a static html file working. This way you can get the Apache and port issues resolved first and then get it working with php.